# Play Framework: Different favicon in production and dev modes

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play Framework 2.1.0 application, and the favicon in production mode is the default Play Framework icon, whereas in development it is an icon I have defined. The same route gives me the default icon in prod, and the correct one in dev.

Here's how I link the favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
```

And I have

```
GET         /assets/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

on my `routes` file. The icon file is in `/public/images` and I compile the app for production with `play clean compile stage`.

Any idea why might the route point to different locations in prod and dev, or why is it defaulting to the Play icon?

Comment: Believe me: I ruled out any cache related issue

Comment: Do you have a favicon.ico still lying around? Does it happen in all browsers? Otherwise no idea, it should work.

Comment: Yes. favicon.ico is there and in prod its route points to my custom favicon.ico, i.e. it works fine. And yes, I've tested it in Chrome, Safari and Firefox and it happens on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a browser cache issue, try with below html.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
```